# How can I make my .NET Core microservice do a recursive health check?

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, health-monitoring

[As described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/monitor-app-health) I can do:

```
checks.AddUrlCheck(Configuration["OrderingUrl"])
```

to make my health check dependant on the health of other Microservices. However,I do not just want to do an url check. I want to do a full health check on the other Microservice (so it will also check the database dependencies etc of the other Microservice). This could be something like,

`checks.AddFullMicroserviceIncludingDatabaseAndUrlCheck(Configuration["OrderingUrl"])` (hypothically).

How can I do such a recursive health check in my .NET Core microservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your microservice you can do whatever you want. Let's say that we have two microservice **A** and **B** and we want to monitor their health check:

**Microservice A**

This microservice uses SQL Server, so we're going to check SQL connection.

```
services.AddHealthChecks(checks =>
{
    checks.AddSqlCheck("ServiceA_DB", Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
});
```

**Microservice B**

This microservice uses SQL server too, but it also uses some other service (for example REST API), so we're going to check SQL connection and the REST API

```
services.AddHealthChecks(checks =>
{
    checks.AddUrlCheck(Configuration["RequiredServiceUrl"]);
    checks.AddSqlCheck("ServiceB_DB", Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
});
```

**Web Status**

Finally we have some web application that monitors these two microservices

```
services.AddHealthChecks(checks =>
{
    checks.AddUrlCheck(Configuration["ServiceAUrl"]);
    checks.AddUrlCheck(Configuration["ServiceBUrl"]);
});
```

It means that if I navigate to `http://webstatus/hc` (health check page), the system checks `http://serviceA/hc` (it checks db), and `http://serviceB/hc` (it checks db and rest api).

Or you can visualize health check of each microservice as shown [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/monitor-app-health) (Figure 10-8)

Comment: So if I add https://www.google.nl/ it should check https://www.google.nl/hc ? That is strange because  I get a "Healthy" status and https://www.google.nl/hc returns a 404.

Comment: AddUrlCheck returns Healthy status if response status code is in successful range (200-299), otherwise it returns Unhealthy

Comment: So why do i get a healthy status when using google.nl ? H

Comment: checks.AddUrlCheck("google.nl") should return Healthy, because the response is 200 OK, but checks.AddUrlCheck("google.nl/hc") should return Unhealthy, because it returns 404 Not Found

Comment: I checked and you're right. The health checks uses status codes indeed. By adding checks.AddUrlCheck("microserviceDependency.nl/hc") I can make it recursive.